# How to easily calculate products of some columns with other list of columns in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say that I have 12 columns in a dataframe. Out of these 12 columns, I have 4 columns that define certain characterists (say, attribute1) and 8 other columns that define another characteristics (say, attribute2).

```
attribute1 <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
attribute2 <- c("col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12")
```

What I want to do is take each column in `attribute1` and multiply with each column in `attribute2`. How can I do this?

The total columns to be added to the dataframe:

```
c("col1xcol5", "col2xcol5", "col3xcol5", "col4xcol5", "col1xcol6", "col2xcol6", "col3xcol6", "col4xcol6", "col1xcol7", "col2xcol7", "col3xcol7", "col4xcol7", "col1xcol8", "col2xcol8", "col3xcol8", "col4xcol8", "col1xcol9", "col2xcol9", "col3xcol9", "col4xcol9", "col1xcol10", "col2xcol10", "col3xcol10", "col4xcol10", "col1xcol11", "col2xcol11", "col3xcol11", "col4xcol11", "col1xcol12", "col2xcol12", "col3xcol12", "col4xcol12")
```

I tried using the following method, but the result doesn't seem to be correct the way I want it where the original columns are intact, and the products are added to the dataframe.

```
df %>% 
mutate(across(attribute1, ~ . * across(attribute2, ~ .x)))
```

Comment: where is an example of your df?

Comment: `df %>%mutate(across(all_of(attribute1) ~.x * across(all_of(attribute2))))`

Answer (score 2):

**1)** To make this reproducible use the built-in `anscombe` with the definitions shown in the Note at the end.

```
plus <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = "+")

sprintf("~.+ (%s):(%s) + 0", plus(attribute1), plus(attribute2)) |>
  formula() |>
  model.matrix(df)
```

giving (continued below)

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4  x1.y1  x1.y2  x2.y1  x2.y2  x3.y1  x3.y2
1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58  80.40  91.40  80.40  91.40  80.40  91.40
2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76  55.60  65.12  55.60  65.12  55.60  65.12
3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71  98.54 113.62  98.54 113.62  98.54 113.62
4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84  79.29  78.93  79.29  78.93  79.29  78.93
5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47  91.63 101.86  91.63 101.86  91.63 101.86
6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04 139.44 113.40 139.44 113.40 139.44 113.40
7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25  43.44  36.78  43.44  36.78  43.44  36.78
8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50  17.04  12.40  17.04  12.40  17.04  12.40
9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56 130.08 109.56 130.08 109.56 130.08 109.56
10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91  33.74  50.82  33.74  50.82  33.74  50.82
```

**2)** The above works if all columns are numeric but if df contains any non-numeric columns, or even if not, then this slightly more general approach will work:

```
sprintf("~ (%s):(%s) + 0", plus(attribute1), plus(attribute2)) |>
  formula() |>
  model.matrix(df) |>
  cbind2(x = df)
```

**3)** The listcompr package provides another way providing list and other comprehensions in a similar manner to python:

```
library(listcompr)

gen.named.matrix("{i}.{j}", df[[i]] * df[[j]], 
     i = attribute1, j = attribute2) |>
   t() |>
   cbind2(x = df)
```

### Note

```
attribute1 <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
attribute2 <- c("y1", "y2")
df <- anscombe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
   transmute(across(all_of(attribute1), ~.x * across(all_of(attribute2))))
```

You can then `cbind` this to your original data

Comment: @G.Grothendieck i was missing a comma. Check the edit

Comment: That gets rid of the error but x1, x2 and x3 are missing from the output.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck generally thats the effect of `mutate` ie replaces the current column with the result of the function. eg `df%>%mutate(across(everything(), ~.x*2))` will double the current columns. Not create new columns. If we need new columns, just use the `.names = {}` argument so that you maintain the current columns and create new columns